# Finding closest set of K disjoint hyperspheres to a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with uniform radius

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory, algorithms, metric-spaces

I am interested in the following problem: in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have $N$ overlapping hyperspheres all with the same radius. Given a point $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the objective is to find the $K$ hyperspheres whose centers are the closest to $p$ under the Euclidean metric (although I'm eventually interested in exploring other metrics as well). However, these hyperspheres cannot overlap with each other.

I think this can be formulated as maximum weighted independent set (with a cardinality constraint) in a geometric graph, where the weights are the distance from $p$, and we have an adjacency matrix where $A_{i,j} = 1$ if $dist(S_i, S_j) < c$ for some constant $c$, but I'm not sure if there is some other formulation I am missing. Is there a name for this problem?

I am also considering this from a probabilistic perspective, in the case where we can assume that the hyperspheres are uniformly distributed.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand: say $n=2$ and $K=4$; what do you consider the answer to be?

Comment: It would depend on the configuration of the circles. If none overlap, then we simply choose the closest two (based on the circle center). If they overlap, then we choose the non overlapping pair that minimizes the distance of the farthest member of the pair.